# Namespaces and type resolution in C# solutions with webservices

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services, types, dependencies

This might get a little convoluted so please let me know if you need clarification.

I have a solution which contains the following projects

```
Project A - WPF application
Project B - ASP.NET application (with exposed webservices)
Project C - Class Library
```

**Both project A and project B reference types that are located in project C, but more importantly project A makes webservice calls to project B using types located in project C.**

The problem I am running into is it appears that when making webservice calls I have no way of referencing the types located in project C directly but rather need to use the types as exposed by the webservice.

Now the basic idea of why this is done I understand (obviously typically the consumer of your webservice would only have the WSDL to go from) however in my case this is an internal application (which is part of a single solution) so this is not a concern.

The biggest problem I see with continuing this approach is that any updates to the types in project C will need to be reflected in project B and then "refreshed" in project A. This seems pretty nasty to me. Surely there is a smoother path?

Am I wrong? What is a typical approach to this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be a little confused here.

The types in `Project C` and the *types* you see when you add a reference to your web service are **different.**

When you added the Web Service reference. Visual Studio used [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx), read metadata from your web service (I'm assuming .asmx?) and then created **proxy classes** for you.

Check the types for the Web Service (they will obviously have the same names). Put your cursor on them and pres <kbd>F12</kbd>. It'll take you to some designer generated code.

So there is no real *workaround* as such. When you update your types in `Project C` and then Update your web services in `Project B` . You will have to **Update Service Reference** from `Project A` Which again uses *svcutil.exe* and regenerates all your proxies.

Also, this is the same way WCF Services work too.

Comment: I understand. Thats exactly my point, that they are different. My concern is the complexity that this adds to the application. (Another problem associated with it that has just hit me is that I implement custom lists of my types and these implement methods to fetch data which now are also broken if I start using the proxy classes)

Comment: True, but there is no way to use your types in `Project C`. VS thankfully has automation that will update/refresh your service references. Its the same thing changes method signatures/types classes etc in your code. If you change it, consumer code will break.

Answer (score 0):

@giddy is correct - the types exposed by the web service are different to the types contained in Project C - even though their definition may be identical.  The web service exposes type information via a wsdl, which Visual Studio uses to generate proxy types.

There is a way around this - you can create an interface which declares all the methods in the web service class, and include it in your shared library.  You can then skip the "Add service reference" process, and create the web service proxy with code (you will not need the proxy classes, as you use the classes in the shared library).

Either way, if you make a change to your data transfer objects or the web service class, you will need to update the client by either by requerying the wsdl using "refresh service reference", or by copying the shared library over.